# Nodejs delete folder on Amazon S3 with aws-sdk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm facing issue of deleting folder which contains photos inside on Amazon S3

1. Create folder

```
var params = {Bucket: S3_BUCKET, Key: "test/", ACL:"public-read"};  
s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {  

});
```

2. Upload photo

```
var body = fs.createReadStream(filePath);  
var params = {Bucket: S3_BUCKET, Key: "test/flower.jpgg", Body: body, ContentType:"image/jpeg", ACL:"public-read"};  

s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {

});
```

3. Delete folder

```
var params = {Bucket: S3_BUCKET, Key: "test/"};  
s3.deleteObject(params, function(err, data) {

});
```

If folder has no photo, delete function works well. But it contains photos, delete will not work.
Please help. Thank for all supports.

Comment: The AWS system will probably log this, but its going to be something to do with items already in the directory. You'll want to delete the contents of the folder, then the folder (Bucket?). If you're not sure how to do this, I'll look up the S3 commands.

Comment: Dandy, I just want to delete folder with all the contents inside it by one command. If there is no command support that, I will try to delete all the contents then delete folder.

Comment: For security reasons, I'd recommend the latter regardless. You don't want to accidentally delete something important.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is a conceptual one, and starts at step 1.

This does not create a folder.  It creates a placeholder object that the console will display as a folder.

> An object named with a trailing "/" displays as a folder in the Amazon S3 console.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/FolderOperations.html

It's not necessary to do this -- creating objects with this key prefix will *still* cause the console to display a folder, even without creating this object.  From the same page:

> Amazon S3 has a flat structure with no hierarchy like you would see in a typical file system. However, for the sake of organizational simplicity, the Amazon S3 console supports the folder concept as a means of grouping objects. Amazon S3 does this by using key name prefixes for objects.

Since, at step 1, you are not actually creating a folder, it makes sense that removing the placeholder object also does not delete the folder.

Folders do not actually exist in S3 -- they're just used for display purposes in the console -- so objects cannot properly be said to be "in" folders.  The only way to remove all the objects "in" a folder is to explicitly remove the objects individually.  Similarly, the only way to rename a folder is to rename the objects in it... and the only way to rename an object is to make a copy of an the object with a new key and then delete the old object.

Comment: Thanks Michael for detailed explanation.

Comment: s3.deleteObjects would simplify deleting all photo before deleting folder object.

Comment: Yes, I assume `deleteObjects` uses the [multi-delete API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/multiobjectdeleteapi.html) so it would be faster and more efficient than individual delete requests.  This is still deleting the objects "individually" in the sense I intended in the answer, since the objects still need to be specified.  Also, note that there's no need to create that folder object at all.

Comment: So should the key be folderNameShown%filename.extension

Comment: Took me a while to figure this out. I put a repl together to show how I have done this https://repl.it/@DrwHarris/Delete-S3-Folder. Hope it helps someone else out.